# Instantiating ObservableIntegerValue in javafx

Tags: javafx, instantiation, observable

I have a variable ObservableIntegerValue called score . 
I wanted to create a listener for it to listen for the changes of its value and according to that change the javafx label text displayed on my pane. 
But in the method initialize() i need to instantiate and give it the initial value of 500 let's say. 
How could it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside an observable value, to make the `score` variable also bindable, you can use `IntegerProperty` instead of `ObservableIntegerValue`. IntegerProperty is an `IntegerExpression`, so it also implements ObservableIntegerValue interface, where IntegerExpression is,

> A IntegerExpression is a ObservableIntegerValue plus additional
>   convenience methods to generate bindings in a fluent style.

```
IntegerProperty score = new SimpleIntegerProperty(500);
Text text = new Text("-");
// Bind score to text, to show on scene.
text.textProperty().bind(score.asString());
score.set(700); // new value
```

and the listener

```
score.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        // value changed
    }
});
```